# MSBuild: Task to embedding a file before compilation

Tags: msbuild

I have the following need:

I'll have to create an MSBuild task that will produce an xml file, which I then need to embed as a resource to one of the projects being built. How do I change my MSBuild proj to accomplish that? Is there a built-in task I can use for embedding the file, or do I need to create one? If the latter, any direction on that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Update: based on the suggestions given, I've ended up adding an empty xml file to the project as a resource, creating a simple MSBuild custom task (http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/15/the-custom-msbuild-task-cookbook.aspx) that writes content to that file as I need it, and running that task as a "BeforeBuild" target. Works like a charm. Note that I've had to "exclude the file from source control", so it won't get checked out every time I build the project, and I've also added some code to the task to make sure the file isn't read-only (http://www.del337ed.com/blog/index.php/2007/09/05/clearing-the-read-only-flag-on-a-file-in-c/).

Comment: Do you let MSBuild just build your VS Solution or are you building your .*proj separately?

Comment: I'm not building the *proj file separately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to create the whole Xml file from scratch and could add a stubb file to your project you could use the [XmlPoke Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598687.aspx) to update this file in the BeforeBuild Target (see Sergios answer).

Comment: ah, yes... that's a great idea. I suppose I'd need to "exclude file from source control" on that one file so I can updated it without having to check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @Claudio Hope you get it to work the way like. My comment about building the solution vs building the project was steering towards whether you'd need to modify your .*proj (BeforeBuild) or could perform any task in a higher lever build script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin in your .csproj/.vbproj file target BeforeBuild (not forget to uncomment it) and [call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) required MSBuild task in BeforeTarget. In that project add that resource as embedded. That's all.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks. Any direction as to how I can add the file as an embedded resource?